# getSelectedExtent not working on joined layers

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcpy

When joining layers the getSelectedExtent function in ArcPy fails to get the extent.  Unjoining the layers and running it yeilds the expected result.  The joined layers are all located on an SDE.  Is this a known issue or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: I would not expect the extent to be determined from the combined files, but rather from the primary file.  Have you tried to export to a new file and get the extent from there?

Comment: The joins are to tables that simply add attributes that I'm using as part of a definition query.   There is no additional geometry.